# How to create read only root type user in Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, readonly

We would like to create a read-only user with access to all the files on the Linux server including the root mount. We came across this [link](https://superuser.com/a/76775/1054893). It looks informative but not very detailed. Could anyone please share detailed steps to create such a user?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the package 'acl' for CentOS, then use the setfacl command.

For example :

1. Create the future read-only user : `adduser roroot`
2. Add read-only and execution to directories : `find / -type d -name "*" ! -path "/<dir>/*" | setfacl -m u:roroot:rx -`    (you should add a ! -path "//* for each dir you don't want to touch, like /pro, /sys, etc)
3. Add read-only for files : `find / -type f -name "*" ! -path "/<dir>/*" | setfacl -m u:roroot:r -`

That does the trick ... kindof. You won't be able to use the any program in /bin or /usr/bin for example. You should change the previous commands to add execution rights to those files to your roroot user. You should probably use `setfacl -R -m u:roroot:rx /bin /bin/*` and `setfacl -R -m u:roroot:rx /lib /lib/*` (and possibly on other lib and bin directories you might want access to)

Comment: Hello Faeeria, Thank you for your suggestion. Seem like ACL's are the only way to achieve this but it would be too much to find and apply ACL on each file and directories ... I hope someone could suggest an easier method.

Comment: Hello ! It is not the only way but what I find to be the easiest way. You could use normal groups but it would probably be more of a hassle because you might already use an authorization strategy based on some groups for some files. When you say that it would be too much, do you mean that in terms of computing power ? Or would you have too many exceptions/files with execution rights needed ?